# How to write a query that outputs the most common combinations with google query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-query

I have a situation where I have a list of transaction IDs containing multiple product combinations. I'm trying to write a query that will show me the most common product combinations. In this sample data, I have the transaction ID in A, which links the products together, and the product name in B. What I want is an output that gives me the information in D and E - it doesn't have to look like that but needs to give the same information.

I would love to share my current workings but I have absolutely no idea how to even begin tackling this one, so any ideas would be warmly received.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1flJ4yM-E8v7A2nRMjjR1J27oqVa-eE5-8wH7TFd6UQg/edit#gid=1452792924

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try this. In C4 put:

```
=unique(A4:A25)
```

In D4 put and copy down:

```
=join(", ",query(FILTER(A4:B25,A4:A25=C4),"Select Col2"))
```

In E4 put and copy down:

```
=JOIN(", ",SORT(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(D4,", ",FALSE))))
```

In F4 put:

```
=QUERY({E:E,E:E},"select Col1, count(Col2) where Col1 != '' group by Col1 order by count(Col2) desc  label count(Col2) ''",1)
```

You can hide Col C, D, & E.

Comment: Awesome! The only issue is that this solution relies on the products being bought in the same order e.g. trousers, shirt, shoes - which is what my test data shows - but what I've found is that if the transaction has the same products but in a different order e.g. shoes, shirt, trousers the solution sees that as a different combination as I guess it's looking for the same string

Comment: Try the revised answer. It sorts the words in the joined cells.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this formula:

`=QUERY(
{UNIQUE(FILTER(A4:A,A4:A>0)),TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(JOIN("",FILTER(B4:B&", "&if(A4:A<>OFFSET(A4:A,1,0),"|",""),A4:A<>0)),", |",0))},
"select Col2, count(Col1) group by Col2 order by count(Col1) desc label count(Col1) ''")`

---

The formula assumes list of Ids is sorted. If not, then I suggest sort the data first.